# how to use the native control plugin in PhoneGap to load a different page into the UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, cordova, uitabbar

I'm using the NativeControls plugin to create a tabbar - http://d.pr/vBJZ

Apparently, on first load, the tabbar has the onSelect event attached to them and i can refresh the webview just fine by doing window.location="http://someremotedomain.com".

But once the webview refreshed with the new external page - it seems the tabbar loses its onSelect event.

I suppose my real question is - why does the tabbar buttons loses its onSelect Event when the webbview starts to show a different (remote/external)page?

Does that mean that i have to re initialize the NativeControls on every new page? that isn't possible because the page im showing is coming from an external source, which doesn't include the phonegaps js related files.

My 2nd question - probably would help me dilemma, is there any way to grab the UIWebView control?

Answer (score 0):

okay nevermind i figured out:

1. the javascript callback function doesn't exist anymore on the next page
2. yes you can - but i don't know in the js file but in the plugin/obj-c you can access the webview